# Cmder wrong colors using Windows Terminal

Tags: windows, terminal, conemu, cmder

I am trying to use Cmder in Windows Terminal. I tried following [this](https://medium.com/talpor/windows-terminal-cmder-%EF%B8%8F-573e6890d143) guide, and I did everything as it says.

However, there is a small issue. No matter what I do, the prompt background colour does not change, it stays black.

[image]

I couldn't figure out the issue. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hey, did you solve that problem? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 4):

In the comments section of the same article

> I ran into this issue as well and was able to get it working. In your
> "%cmder_root%\config" directory, create a file called "my_prompt.lua"
> and add the following to it:

```
function my_prompt_filter()
  cwd = clink.get_cwd()
  prompt = "\x1b[1;32;49m{cwd} {git}{hg}{svn} \n\x1b[1;39;49m{lamb} \x1b[0m"
  new_value = string.gsub(prompt, "{cwd}", cwd)
  clink.prompt.value = string.gsub(new_value, "{lamb}", "λ")
  end
  clink.prompt.register_filter(my_prompt_filter, 1)
```

Kudos to [Eric Grandt](https://medium.com/@ericgrandt)

Comment: It works for a bit, but if I cd into a git directory, the git branch info messes with the colours again. Moving the `49m` bit to the proper place would do the trick, I think, but I don't understand where to yet.

Comment: Never mind. Removing the `{git}{hg}` bit did it.

Comment: That's weird, this solution worked for me. Anyhow, glad that a minor tweak worked 

Comment: In the `prompt` variable remove everything except the variables in `{ }` i.e., replace the variable initialization with `prompt = "{cwd} {git}{hg}{svn} \n{lamb}"`

Answer (score 1):

@AMagyar 's answer is great, except that if you use conda, pyenv or other virtual environments, that information would be omitted (when it should be `(base) λ`, you will get `λ`). Instead, you can create `my_prompt.lua` as something like:

```
function my_prompt_filter()
    local prompt = clink.prompt.value
    prompt = string.gsub(prompt, '^\x1b%[1;32;40m', '\x1b[1;32;49m')
    prompt = string.gsub(prompt, '\n\x1b%[1;39;40m', '\n\x1b[1;39;49m')
    clink.prompt.value = prompt
end
clink.prompt.register_filter(my_prompt_filter, 1)
```

Everything is settled.

#### What controls the terminal text & background color?

In function `set_prompt_filter` in `%cmder_root%\vender\clink.lua`, you may read lines like:

```lua
local cmder_prompt = "\x1b[1;32;40m{cwd} {git}{hg}{svn} \n\x1b[1;39;40m{lamb} \x1b[0m"
```

This is the prototype of cmder prompts. The {cwd}, {git}, {lamb}, etc, are to be substituted with the actual content later on. The `\x1b[1;32;40m` is the [ANSI escape sequence](https://gist.github.com/fnky/458719343aabd01cfb17a3a4f7296797) that controls the color of following text. `32` means green text color, **`40` means black background color**, `39` means default text color, and `49` means default background color.

#### Why was pyenv/conda environment omitted?

Also in function `set_prompt_filter` in `%cmder_root%\vender\clink.lua`, you may find how cmder added the information of virtual environments into `{lamb}` (or more specifically, prompts with `()` or `[]`). So either you have to retrieve that information from the original prompt, or simply just replace the color codes, as in this answer.